# How do I combine dateadd and convert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that shows the month (converted from date of day):

```
DECLARE @Month varchar(6) = '202101'

SELECT
    [Month] = CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(Date)) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(Date)), 2),
    Conversion_Rate, 
    ID
FROM 
    X
WHERE 
    CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(Date)) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(Date)), 2) = @Month
```

Now I want it to show the previous month as well, counting 1 backwards from the declared month using `DATEADD`. How can I do this?

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not so tricky to post properly formatted code. Edit the question, paste the code, highlight it, and click `{}`.

Comment: What is the data type of Month column?

Comment: The data type is date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dateadd(month,-1,date)** will do the trick. **month** is indicating that you want to add months to the date and adding **-1** will give you the previous month:

```
DECLARE @Month varchar(6) = '202101'

SELECT
    [Month] = CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(Date)) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(Date)), 2),
    [PreviousMonth] = CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(dateadd(month,-1,'Date'))) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(dateadd(month,-1,'Date'))), 2),
    Conversion_Rate, 
    ID
FROM 
    X
WHERE 
    CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(Date)) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(Date)), 2) = @Month
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `DATEADD()` function and add `-1` to the `month` datepart of the `[date]` column. You may also simplify the statement:

```
DECLARE @Month varchar(6) = '202101'
SELECT
    [Month] = CONVERT(varchar(6), [date], 112),
    [Previous_Month] = CONVERT(varchar(6), DATEADD(month, -1, [date]), 112),
    Conversion_Rate, 
    ID
FROM X
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(6), [date], 112) = @Month
```

As an additional note, consider the fact that indexes on the `[date]` column cannot be used if `CONVERT()` is used in `WHERE` clause for that column.

Comment: This is the better answer. To improve query efficiency, the conversion can be eliminated from the `WHERE` by calculating and comparing a half-open date interval. `DECLARE @MonthStart DATE = '2021-01-01`, `DECLARE @MonthEndExclusive DATE = DATEADD(month, 1, @MonthStart)` and then `WHERE date >= @MonthStart AND date < @MonthEndExclusive`. Note the use of `<` instead of `<=`. The interval end is immediately before 00:00:00 of the following day. This eliminates any need for date/time truncation and allows the query optimizer to use an index on `date`.

Answer (score 2):

**Store dates as `date` not `varchar`, then the server can use the indexes properly.**

```sql
DECLARE @Month date = '2021-01-01'

SELECT
    [Month] = CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(Date)) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(Date)), 2),
    [PreviousMonth] = CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(dateadd(month,-1,'Date'))) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(dateadd(month,-1,'Date'))), 2),
    Conversion_Rate, 
    ID
FROM 
    X
WHERE 
    Date >= @Month AND Date < DATEADD(month, 1, @Month);
```

Note the use of the half-open interval `>= AND <`

Comment: This combined with the simplified `CONVERT(varchar(6), ... , 112)` from @Zhorov's post would be the optimal answer.